# Process to restart Namenode in IBM BigInsights (enabled GPFS - a transparency layer of HDFS)

Tags: hadoop, biginsights, namenode

I am working on IBM Hadoop distribution (BigInsights) which has been installed using Apache Ambari and currently, has GPFS (general parallel file system) enabled as a transparency layer of HDFS. On Ambari, we have enabled maintenance mode on HDFS and making any changes to core/hdfs-site.xml is not possible through Ambari console. So, if I want to make any changes to core/hdfs-site.xml, I have to make them from server side using CLI then how I must restart my namenode/datanode in GPFS environment? Do I need restart the connector which will enable new parameters or restarting namenode? If connector works then I do have the command "mmhadoopctl" but if not, what is command I must use to enable new parameters placed inside the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If the underneath file system is GPFS (non-HDFS), why it still has namenode and datanodes running? I would suspect GPFS has separate configuration files and won't be aware whatever you have set in hdfs-site.xml.

Irrespectively, restarting namenode is pretty simple, log on as hdfs user and run `hadoop-daemon.sh stop namenode` then `hadoop-daemon.sh stop namenode`, hadoop-daemon.sh script is under the sbin of HADOOP_HOME.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Well, although it is GPFS but running Hadoop does need a namenode and datanode by its architecture. If we type `mmhadoopctl connector getstate`, I can see namenode and datanodes are running under GPFS layer:  _ipaddress: namenode running as process 1234
ipaddress: datanode running as process 33433
ipaddress: datanode running as process 23231
ipaddress: datanode running as process 12343_. I know how to restart the daemons in normal distribution but want to know how we must do when GPFS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Spectrum Scale (GPFS) provides its own namenode service (and datanode services too). This though is only a wrapper over the underlying Spectrum Scale filesystem and Spectrum Scale metadata. The NameNode service is stateless, as for example all information about the files, ACLs and so on is kept in Spectrum Scale (and can be seen from the command line using POSIX and Spectrum Scale command-line tools.

`/usr/lpp/mmfs/hadoop/sbin/mmhadoopctl connector stop`

`/usr/lpp/mmfs/hadoop/sbin/mmhadoopctl connector start`

`/usr/lpp/mmfs/hadoop/sbin/mmhadoopctl connector getstate`

ie do it using GPFS commands, not the generic Hadoop NameNode service